# I would like to run for loop to each of li tag and want to add content dynamically from django backend admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have created a navbar and content can be added from the backend but only the home nav bar shows the icon and the other navbar name is with the same icon. I want to add a different nav bar with a different icon. and want to run if, elif and else condition. please help me how to use if elif and else dynamically.

**initial HTML without dynamic content**

```
<!-- Nav Links -->
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link fs-5" href="#समाचार">
          <i class="fas fa-address-book mr-1">
          </i>समाचार
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link fs-5" href="/">
          <i class="fas fa-home mr-1"></i>
          होमपेज
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link fs-5" href="#भिडियो">
          <i class="far fa-clone mr-1">
          </i>भिडियो
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link fs-5" href="#विजनेस">
          <i class="far fa-calendar-alt mr-1">
          </i>विजनेस
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link fs-5" href="#ग्यालरी">
          <i class="far fa-chart-bar mr-1">
          </i>ग्यालरी
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link fs-5" href="#प्रोफाइल">
          <i class="far fa-copy mr-1">
          </i>प्रोफाइल
        </a>
      </li>
```

**Dynamic backend added HTML which suppose to change in order to work:**

```
{% for i in nav_data %}
      {% if forloop.first %}  
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link fs-5" href="/">
          <i class="fas fa-home mr-1"></i>
          {{i.name}}
        </a>
      </li>
      {% elif forloop.first %}
      <a class="nav-link fs-5" href="/">
        <i class="fas fa-home mr-1"></i>
        {{i.name}}
      </a>
      {% else %} 
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link fs-5" href="#भिडियो">
          <i class="far fa-clone mr-1">
          </i>{{i.name}}
        </a>
      </li>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

*Note: need to use if, elif and else condition in each li and i.name should give value from backend in accending order.

Answer (score 0):

Remove {% forloop.first %} from elif condition
you are giving same conditions for both if and elif